# Llamadas a funciones sin ()

Tags: javascript

No entiendo por qué hay veces que las llamadas a funciones en JavaScript se hace sin añadirle ().
En este ejemplo:

```js
    function boton(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('Presioné Botón');
    }
    document.querySelector('#pulsador').addEventListener('click',boton);
```

Se llama a la funcion "boton" sin añadirle () al final.
Yo escribiría la última línea de esta forma:

```js
document.querySelector('#pulsador').addEventListener('click',boton());
```

¿Qué diferencia hay entre poner () al final de la llamada de una función y no poner los ()?
Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Acceder a una función sin () devolverá el objeto de función y hacerlo con () te dará el resultado de la función.